# React-dnd useDrop in both child and parent components

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

[image: Blue event dropped onto yellow]

Red boxes are parent Drop targets, green boxes are child drop targets.

Parent drop targets are used for placing the children to the cell.
Children drop targets are used for ordering them.

### Parent component useDrop

```
const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: DraggableTypes.EVENT,
        drop: (item) => {
            return { date: props.day.date, copy: keyPressed }
        }
    }), [props.day.date, keyPressed])
```

### Children component useDrop and useDrag

```
function CalendarLayout(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const [, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: DraggableTypes.EVENT,
        item: props.event,
        collect: monitor => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
        }),
        end: (item, monitor) => {
            const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
            console.log(dropResult)
        }
    }), [props.event.id, props.event.order]);
    const [, drop] = useDrop({
        accept: DraggableTypes.EVENT,
        drop: (item, monitor) => {
            return {
                date: props.event.date,
                copy: false,
                order: props.event.order,         
            };
        },
   
    }, [props.event.order]);
```

So when I drop blue event to the yellow one, in monitor.getDropResult I get result from the Parent component, but i need Child one. Can smb tell if there is useDrop priority? Or other way to get the dropResult I need

Answer (score 0):

you can try isOver and handlerId to maintain 2 separate div for the parent as well as child component and you can identify whether the item is in a parent or in a child component you would need to maintain different refs. 1 for parent and 1 for child.

```js
use ref(null)

//parent component

const [{cardOver,item},drop]=useDrop({ accept :x,  
drop:()=>{//function for handling drop in parent},
   collect: (monitor) => ({
       item: monitor.getItem(),
       cardOver: monitor.isOver(),
     }),
drop(parent_ref)
<dndProvider backend={HTML5backend}>
<childComponent/>
<dndProvider/>

//similarly in child component

  const [{ item, handlerId, isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
      accept: //if more then 1 type to be accepted:[x,y],
      drop: () => {
       //function for handling childItem
      },
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        item: monitor.getItem(),
        handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId(),
        isOver: monitor.isOver(),
      }),
    });
```

it might help you

the handlerID would help for the identification of drag drop in child component or As an unique id for the child components while droping